# Using Retrofit2 along with recyclerview for nested JSON, response incompatibility

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, gson, retrofit2

So, I have been trying to parse and display a nested JSON into recycler view using retrofit2.

The problem that I am facing is that the response is not compatible with the object.
The following code and the representation will help the reader understand better.

```
public class FragmentTransaction extends Fragment {

Transactions transactions;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
TransactionsAdapter transactionsAdapter;
private View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    transactionsAdapter = new TransactionsAdapter(getContext(), transactions);   //first occurrence of error
    recyclerView.setAdapter(transactionsAdapter);
    APIInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
    Call<Transactions> call = apiInterface.getTransactionList(sharedPreferences.getString(UNIQUE_ID, "qwe"));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Transactions>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Transactions> call, Response<Transactions> response) {

            transactions = response.body();
            Log.d("5", "Passing to Adapter");
            try {
                transactionsAdapter.setTransactionsList(transactions);   //second occurrence of error

                Log.d("4", "Passed to Adapter");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Transactions> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("6", "Passing to Adapter Failure", t);
        }
    });
```

in both the cases the error is

> 'TransactionsAdapter(android.content.Context, java.util.List)' in 'in.sid.POJO.TransactionsAdapter' cannot be applied to '(android.content.Context, in.sid.POJO.Transactions)'

A visual representation

[image]

Also, I tried to change the recyclerviewadapter to work without List<>, but I couldn't make it work and I cannot change the API call because when I did that, it gives me the following error

> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Lastly, I would be happy to provide more information but for now I am Keeping this small.

**Update 1**

**Adapter Class**

```
public class TransactionsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TransactionsAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
private Context context;
private List <Transactions> TransactionsList;


public TransactionsAdapter(Context context, List<Transactions> TransactionsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.TransactionsList = TransactionsList;
}

public void setTransactionsList(List<Transactions> transactionsList){
    this.TransactionsList = transactionsList;

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public TransactionsAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TransactionsAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Transactions transactionsList = TransactionsList.get(position);
    Transactions.DataEntity dataEntity = transactionsList.getData().get(0);
    holder.associateName.setText(dataEntity.getAssociate().getName());
   }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView associateName;
    TextView transactionDate;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        associateName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameAssociate);
        transactionDate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateTransaction);
}
}
}
```

**Response**

```
{
"status": "success",
"status_code": "200",
"data": [
    {
        "transaction_id": "2",
        "transaction_date": "2018-04-19 05:27:23.0",
        "amount": "200.00",
        "user_id": "2",
        "currency": "MXN",
        "associate_id": "1",
        "associate": {
            "is_active": "N",
            "associate_type": "Autoservicio",
            "name": "alsuper",
            "created_date": "12-Feb-2018 07:31:58 AM",
            "associate_id": "1",
            "url": null,
            "last_update_date": "12-Feb-2018 07:31:58 AM"
        },
        "card_id": "2",
        "card": {
            "bank_code": "002",
            "is_active": "Y",
            "allows_charges": "Y",
            "card_number": "411111XXXXXX1111",
            "openpay_card_id": "kiusphu8moqri6qys7sg",
            "type": "debit",
            "card_id": "2",
            "expiration_year": "21",
            "user_id": "2",
            "expiration_month": "10",
            "bank_name": "bank name",
            "created_date": "21-Mar-2018 05:46:58 AM",
            "brand": "visa",
            "last_update_date": "21-Mar-2018 05:46:58 AM",
            "holder_name": "name name name name"
        }
    }
]
}
```

**POJO Class**

```
public class Transactions {

@SerializedName("data")
private List<DataEntity> data;
@SerializedName("status_code")
private String statusCode;
@SerializedName("status")
private String status;

public List<DataEntity> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<DataEntity> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public String getStatusCode() {
    return statusCode;
}

public void setStatusCode(String statusCode) {
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public static class DataEntity {
    @SerializedName("card")
    private CardEntity card;
    @SerializedName("card_id")
    private String cardId;
    @SerializedName("associate")
    private AssociateEntity associate;
    @SerializedName("associate_id")
    private String associateId;
    @SerializedName("currency")
    private String currency;
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    private String userId;
    @SerializedName("amount")
    private String amount;
    @SerializedName("transaction_date")
    private String transactionDate;
    @SerializedName("transaction_id")
    private String transactionId;
}

public static class CardEntity {
    @SerializedName("holder_name")
    private String holderName;
    @SerializedName("last_update_date")
    private String lastUpdateDate;
    @SerializedName("brand")
    private String brand;
    @SerializedName("created_date")
    private String createdDate;
    @SerializedName("bank_name")
    private String bankName;
    @SerializedName("expiration_month")
    private String expirationMonth;
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    private String userId;
    @SerializedName("expiration_year")
    private String expirationYear;
    @SerializedName("card_id")
    private String cardId;
    @SerializedName("type")
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("openpay_card_id")
    private String openpayCardId;
    @SerializedName("card_number")
    private String cardNumber;
    @SerializedName("allows_charges")
    private String allowsCharges;
    @SerializedName("is_active")
    private String isActive;
    @SerializedName("bank_code")
    private String bankCode;
}

public static class AssociateEntity {
    @SerializedName("last_update_date")
    private String lastUpdateDate;
    @SerializedName("associate_id")
    private String associateId;
    @SerializedName("created_date")
    private String createdDate;
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("associate_type")
    private String associateType;
    @SerializedName("is_active")
    private String isActive;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: add your adapter class and also response

Comment: @Pavya Please check the updated question.

Comment: transactionsAdapter = new TransactionsAdapter(getContext(), transactions); Here you need transactions as a List. And check your Transactions pogo class

Comment: @Pavya I don't understand this comment. Would you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create  `private ArrayList<DataEntity> listItems = new ArrayList<>();`

Then in set adapter

```
transactionsAdapter = new TransactionsAdapter(getContext(), listItems);
```

And in onResponse

```
listItems.addAll(response.body().getData());
```

Comment: This did the job.

Comment: also check null for  response.body().getData()

Comment: Hey, after so much troubles, my recycler View is showing only one entry, the first one to be exact, any idea why so ?

Comment: its because of you are getting only one object in data. Check your response

Comment: Actually I truncated the response in my question here, but I am getting a series of objects at once and each object starts from transaction_id and ends at Holder_name

Comment: in item layout check height might be its match parent. Then it to wrap conten

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176460/discussion-between-siddhant-ghosh-and-pavya).

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return TransactionsList.size();
    }
```

Comment: I certainly forgot about this, not the correct answer for the situation but a valuable one indeed

Answer (score 0):

these error occurs when server response and your POJO class mismatch.
looking at the error check for the array in your POJO class and server response, server response might be sending array as string and your POJO class is trying to map string for an array.

Comment: Your concern is correct but if you look again, my error is different than what you said. My error and the entire problem is between the mismatch of the adapter class of recycler view and the server response, My POJO classes are working just fine.

Comment: can you post your POJO class too?

Comment: your are passing whole body into adapter, you need to pass only data array and it might work fine.

Comment: Ok I would try that. Any more suggestions ?